# A Yearly data to Daily data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
 df: (DataFrame)
         Open High Close Volume   
2020/1/1  1    2    3     323232
2020/1/2  2    3    4     321321
....
2020/12/31 4   5    6     123213
....
2021
```

The performance i needed is : (Graph NO.1)

```
        Open High Close Volume  Year_Sum_Volume
2020/1/1  1   2     3    323232   (323232 + 321321 +....+ 123213)
2020/1/2  2   3     4    321321   (323232 + 321321 +....+ 123213)
....
2020/12/31 4  5     6    123213   (323232 + 321321 +....+ 123213)
....
2021                              (x+x+x.....x)
```

I want a sum of Volume in different year (the Year_Sum_Volume is the volume of each year)
This is the code i try to calculate the sum of volume in each year but how can i add this data
to daily data , i want to add Year_Sum_Volume to df,like(Graph no.1)

```
df.resample('Y', on='Date')['Volume'].sum()
```

thanks you for answering

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, *Year_Sum_Volume* is the same value for every row and can be calculated using `df['Volume'].sum()`.

Then you join a column of a scaled list:

`df.join(pd.DataFrame( {'Year_Sum_Volume': [your_sum_val] * len(df['Volume'])} ))`

Comment: Hello i need  the sum of volume in each year btw thanks you for answering

Comment: @Wilson What is stopping you from calculating it for each year? You only showed us the year 2020.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `groupby.sum()` and merge should be your friends

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":['2021-12-30', '2021-12-31', '2022-01-01'], "a":[1,2.1,3.2]})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df["year"] = df.date.dt.year
df_sums = df.groupby("year").sum().rename(columns={"a":"a_sum"})
df = df.merge(df_sums, right_index=True, left_on="year")
```

which gives:

|  | date | a | year | a_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-12-30 00:00:00 | 1 | 2021 | 3.1 |
| 1 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | 2.1 | 2021 | 3.1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 3.2 | 2022 | 3.2 |

Comment: Hi Bizzinho you got the point thanks you for answering

Comment: Great ,in this case I suggest to accept the reply? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code (after converting **date** column to pd.to_datetime)

```
df.assign(Year_Sum_Volume = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year)['a'].transform('sum'))
```